# Докер, постоянная синхронизация Mysql базы с контейнера на локаль

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

изучаю докер и не могу никак понять вещь, мне нужно чтобы была синхронизация базы данных с контейнера на локаль. Я пробовал так:

```
    volumes:
  - ./database_on_local:/var/lib/mysql
```

Но при создании базы данных в контейнере, этот пункт его перекраивает, и получается что удаляет базу сформированную в контейнере и замещает собой ею.

Структура файлов такая:

```
req.txt
venv
database:
  dockerfile
docker-compose.yaml
```

Код в Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb


COPY dump.sql dump.sql
RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &" && \
  sleep 5 && \
  mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE bot_different_utilities" && \
  mysql -u root bot_different_utilities < /dump.sql
```

Код в docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    build: ./database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database_on_local:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Можно конечно делать дамп через скрипты каждую минуту, или ещё какой-то костыль приделать, если конечно то, что я хочу возможно. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Dockerfile создать папку с содержимым для последующего подключения тома?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299487/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-dockerfile-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0) Было смутное чувство, что подобный вопрос уже задавался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так, для использования дампа вам потребуется прописать вот такой код в волюмях:

```
  db:
#    build: ./database
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database_on_local:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Первое - синхронизация с хранилищем железа, второе - инициализация вашего дампа.
(не забудьте прописать CREATE DATABASE db_name и USE db_name ибо не все дамперы это делают)

Answer (score 3):

Поведение, которое вы получаете - ожидаемое.

Инструкции из `Dockerfile` выполняются по команде `docker build ...`. В результате создается образ, который содержит файловую систему. В вашем случае в файловой системе вы создаете файлы БД.

Далее по команде `docker run ...` этот образ используется и если вы используете bind volumes, то директория с хоста монтируется в файловую систему контейнера *перекрывая* то, что там уже было.

Докер не умеет то, что вы хотите. Идея такая, что в контейнере не нужно хранить данные, контейнер можно в любой момент убить или перезапустить. Его состояние не сохраняется. Все важные данные нужно хранить в присоединяемых томах (volumes).

Правильным решением будет запуск создания БД не на этапе сборки образа, а уже на этапе запуска контейнера.

Comment: Спасибо, мои догадки подтвердились, то есть придётся писать отдельный скрипт для разворачивания из дампа бдшки...